# How to convert from f(x) form to slope-intercept form?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I have an equation

> $f$( x + d )

which is the same as

> y = x - d.

My question is how to convert between the two? I know this specific example is obvious although for more complicated questions I would like to know how to do so. thanks

Comment: You tagged your question as linear algebra and functional analysis. Is $f$ a linear function/operator?

Comment: $f(x+d)$ is not an equation, there is no $=$ sign.

Comment: hi @Roland, apologies for the wrong tag. and by f(x + d), I meant the equation " f(x + d) = x ". i excluded the " = x " because that is how it is portrayed in my homework question.

Comment: So you have $f(x+d)=x$ and you want to switch to $f(x)$? This would be $$f(x)=f((x-d)+d)=(x-d)=x-d$$.